# Create exe file from .c and .h files

Tags: windows, makefile, gnu-make

I want to use a exe that will create a triangle strip. I have found the link with code. It has a set of .c and .h files which has to be compiled using the given make file. But when i try to run the make file in cmd promt of windows, it says make is not recognized as a internal command. I need help to create a exe for this. [Here is the link for the code](http://www2.cs.cas.cz/~sima/htgen-en.html).

There is a download and install instruction in the link i provided. But that is of not much help to me. I am stuck. Please help me create this exe. Thank you

Here is the actual make file content

CC = gcc

CCFLAGS = -ansi -pedantic

MODULES = input.o hnet.o comp.o tstrips.o ts_msgs.o

prog: htgen

htgen: $(MODULES)
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -lm -o htgen $(MODULES)

input.o: ts_msgs.h ts_types.h input.h input.c 
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c input.c
hnet.o: ts_msgs.h ts_types.h input.h hnet.h hnet.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c hnet.c
comp.o: ts_msgs.h ts_types.h comp.h comp.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c comp.c
ts_msgs.o: ts_msgs.h ts_msgs.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c ts_msgs.c
tstrips.o: ts_msgs.h input.h hnet.h comp.h tstrips.h tstrips.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c tstrips.c

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    -rm *~ htgen $(MODULES)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will probably take a few tries. Use Cygwin as @Misha suggested, and do this:

```
cd /cygdrive/c/Users/vinod/Downloads/htgen-src/htgen-src
make
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Windows?

There are two routes to go:

1. Install Linux (rather easy). I would use something like Wubi to install Ubuntu.
   Take a look here:
   http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/windows-installer . You run the program and in 30 minutes you have Ubuntu on your computer. It includes an uninstaller that removes Ubuntu like a normal Windows program.
2. Use cygwin to "install" these commands in Windows. I would do this in parralel to installing an IDE such as NetBeans. Take a look at http://netbeans.org/community/releases/69/cpp-setup-instructions.html .

Comment: Yes I am using Windows. I tried using the Cygwin cmd promt as suggested. I run the command "$ make /cygdrive/c/Users/vinod/Downloads/htgen-src/htgen-src/Makefile" and i get message "make: Nothing to be done for `/cygdrive/c/Users/vinod/Downloads/htgen-src/htgen-src/Makefile'". There is no exe created. I have edited my question with makefile content. Please help me with this. Thank you.